# jquery remove class from li if there is no ul child

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class from an li if it doesn't have a ul child.

Something like this?  Not anywhere close I'm sure, but it will give you an idea.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

$('ul not(li:has(ul)')).removeClass('dropdown');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script

```
$("li").each(function(){
   if($(this).find('ul').length === 0) {
       $(this).children("abc")
   }
})
```

```css
 
.abc {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <ul>
<li class="abc">a</li>
<li  class="abc">a</li>
<li class="abc">a</li>
<li class="abc">a</li>
<li class="abc">a</li>
<li class="abc">a
  <ul>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
    <li class="abc">a</li>
  </ul>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
$("li").each(function(){
   if($(this).children('ul').length === 0) {
   $(this).removeClass("abc")
   }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('ul li').not('ul').removeClass('dropdown');
```

But i realy not understanding question.